# Difference Of Dates in Linq To Entities

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the no. of days by subtracting 2 dates, but both these trials say - 'DataSet does not support system.Nullable<>

```
public DataTable GetData()
{
    var qry = from a in MyDB.tblBranch.Where(a.EntryDate.HasValue && 
              a.exitdate.hasvalue)
              join e in MyDB.tblEmp on a.Eid equals e.Eid
              select new
              {
                 id = a.branchid,
                 name = e.empname,
                 days = System.Data.Objects
                        .EntityFunctions.DiffDays(a.ExitDate,a.EnterDate)

              };
     DataTable dt = qry.ToDataTable();
     return dt;
}
```

Comment: This code can't even compile. Please edit your question.

Comment: I edited the OP's code, looks like he forgot to comment the line `DateDiff("dd",a.ExitDate,a.EnterDate)` which is belong to the second trial. (he mentioned 2 trials).

Comment: @King..yes. michael,my code works fine otherwise, its just this column/line thats causing the problem. I updated my question anyways.

Answer (score 0):

`EntityFunctions.DiffDays()` returns `Nullable<int>`, so you have to deal with null results

for example

```
qry
    .Where(d => d.days.HasValue)
    .Select(d => d.Value)
```

**edit**

try smth like that

```
var qry = MyDB.tblBranch
    .Where(a=>a.branchid==1)
    .Select(a => new
    {
        days = System.Data.Objects
            .EntityFunctions.DiffDays(a.ExitDate,a.EnterDate)
    })
    .Where(d => d.days.HasValue)
    .Select(d => d.Value);

DataTable dt = qry.ToDataTable();
```

if you want to keep null values then you can do smth like this

```
var qry = MyDB.tblBranch
    .Where(a=>a.branchid==1)
    .Select(a => new
    {
        days = System.Data.Objects
            .EntityFunctions
            .DiffDays(a.ExitDate,a.EnterDate)
    })
    .Select(b => b.HasValue ? (Object) b.Value :  DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: could you help me, how it would go in my code. I am unable to figure it out

Comment: I dont see 'where' after };.---will this work in linqtoentites.

Comment: have yo tried my code? please see edits and if it gives any exceptions write them please

Comment: I dont get select, where options at all, after '}.'

Comment: sorry, forgot to put bracket after `}`

Comment: @Ruby, sorry, need to go, will be write in 3-4 hours

Comment: @Ruby do you get compile time error or runtime and what is it text?

Comment: Yes, the error is the same in question. WHy is the current code not working. I have updated my question

Comment: @Ruby as i said at begining of my answer your current code doesn't work because `EntityFunctions.DiffDays() returns Nullable<int>` and `DataTable` doesn't support nullable types, so you need to cast your nullable in  smth else. Have you tried anything from my code?